# Rational canonical form of diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, free-modules

I'm trying to determine the rational canonical form of a diagonal matrix 
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & a_2 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots\\
0 &0 & \cdots & a_n
\end{pmatrix}
$$ where the $a_i$'s are all different. If my intuition is correct, since the characteristic polynomial (in this case also the minimal polynomial) of $A$ is just the product $(x-a_1)\cdots(x-a_n)$ and all the factors are different we have that the $(x-a_i)$'s are the invariant factors of $A$. Then the rational canonical form of $A$ is again $A$.

Is this correct? Is there a more formal way to work this problem? I'd appreciate any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, $A$ in this case is the [rational canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form) of $A$.  You might consult (or refer to) the definition.

Answer (score 6):

I totally disagree with the answers given previously. The authors confuse the Frobenius normal form with the primary rational canonical form.

The Frobenius decomposition has the following form

$F:=diag(C_{p_1},\cdots,C_{p_k})$ where the $C_{p_i}$ are the companion matrices of the polynomial $p_i$, and overall, $p_i$ is a divisor of $p_{i+1}$. In particular, $p_k$ is the minimal polynomial and $p_1\cdots p_k$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

When the eigenvalues of $A$ are distinct, then the vector $(1,\cdots,1)$ is cyclic over whole vector space $K^n$.

Then the Frobenius form of $A$ is $F=C_p$ where $p$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

It suffices to convince oneself to test in Maple

"FrobeniusForm (DiagonalMatrix ([1,2,3]);"

Comment: We get one big companion block, where you have to work out all the linear factors like:
$$ (x-\lambda_1)\dots(x-\lambda_n) =$$ 
$$x^n - \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i x^{n-1} +(\lambda_1 \lambda_2 + \lambda_1 \lambda_3+ \dots + \lambda_{n-1} \lambda_n)x^{n-2} + \dots +  (-1)^{n-1} (\lambda_2 \lambda_3\dots \lambda_n + \dots + \lambda_1 \lambda_2 \dots \lambda_{n-1})x +  (-1)^n \prod_{i=1}^n \lambda_i$$
$n=3$
$$(x-\lambda_1)(x-\lambda_2)(x-\lambda_3)=x^3 - (\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3)x^2+ (\lambda_1 \lambda_2+
\lambda_1 \lambda_3 + \lambda_2 \lambda_3)x  - \lambda_1 \lambda_2 \lambda_3.$$

Comment: Then use page 475 of dummit and foote to find the associated companion block. (or any other textbook/reference that explains companion matrices)

Comment: $n=3$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 &  \lambda_1 \lambda_2 \lambda_3 \\
1 & 0 & -(\lambda_1 \lambda_2 +\lambda_1  \lambda_3 +\lambda_2 \lambda_3) \\
0 & 1 & \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the rational canonical form is just $A$. Your intuition is good, but can be expounded futher:

Let $V$ be a vector space where the matrix of some linear operator $T$ is represented by $A$ in some basis. Since $A$ is diagonal, $T$ is a diagonalizable operator, so $V$ has a basis where each vector is an eigenvector for $T$. The Cyclic Decomposition Theorem lets us decompose $V$ into a direct sum of $T$-cyclic subspaces for some vectors $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_k$. Namely, we can decompose $V$ as:

$$V = Z(\alpha_1; T) \oplus ... \oplus Z(\alpha_n; T)$$

Where $Z(\alpha_i; T) = \{ v \in V: v = g(T) \alpha_i \ \text{ for some polynomial } \ g(x) \}$, and  $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ are the distinct eigenvectors of $A$.

These subspaces are invariant under $T$, so let $T_i$ be the operator induced by $T$ on $Z(\alpha_i; T)$. Then $T_i$ has minimal polynomial $p_i(x) = x - a_i$, where $a_i$ is the eigenvalue corresponding to the eigenvector $\alpha_i$. Since $\dim(Z(\alpha_i; T)) = 1$ and $T_i$ has a cyclic vector, we get that the rational form of $T_i$ is just its $1 \times 1$ companion matrix:

$A_i = \begin{bmatrix} a_i \end{bmatrix}$.

Thus $$A = A_1 \oplus ... \oplus A_n = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 & 0 &... & 0 \\ 0 & a_2 & ... & 0 \\ . \\ . \\ 0 & 0 & ... & a_n \end{bmatrix}$$

Is the rational form of $A$