# Find a matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ is in rational form

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let  $A=\begin{pmatrix}
> 1 &3  &3 \\3 
>  &1  &3 \\3 
>  &-3  &-5 
> \end{pmatrix}$
>
> The exercise ask for a matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ is in  rational form.

Since $\det (xI-A)=(x+2)(x-4)(x+5)$ then $A$ is diagonalizable, so I can get a matrix $Q$ such that

$$A=
Q\begin{pmatrix}
4 &  & \\ 
 &  -5& \\ 
 &  & -2
\end{pmatrix}Q^{-1}
$$

I think since $A$ is similar to $
\begin{pmatrix}
4 &  & \\ 
 &  -5& \\ 
 &  & -2
\end{pmatrix}
$ then $Q=P$ solves the problem.

Is that correct? note that in this question: [Rational canonical form of diagonal matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2568628/rational-canonical-form-of-diagonal-matrix) the rational form of a diagonal matrix is the same matrix.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "in rational form"?

Comment: Rational canonical form: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RationalCanonicalForm.html